# Sender Authentication Package - Private IP is provisioned, but don't see it in Delivery Profile

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability

My client received notification from Salesforce that their private IP that was purchased as part of their Sender Authentication Package was provisioned and ready to use in the Marketing Cloud account.  However, I do not see this as an available option to select under Delivery Profiles.  Am I missing something here?  The radio button is grayed out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP provided IP *is* the one under Account Default option for that MID.

So unless your client purchased another IP to use in Marketing Cloud, there will not be an option to select anything else.